# Как сделать карточки в bootstrap 4 одинаковой высоты

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать карточки в bootstrap 4 одинаковой высоты, в которых разный текст. И из за этой мелочи карточки разной высоты.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Приведение к одной высоте блоков с разным количеством текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628415/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте bootstrap правильно и будет вам счастье.

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class=row>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto dolorem dolores, est fuga fugiat officiis sunt vero voluptates
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto dolorem dolores, est fuga fugiat officiis sunt vero voluptates. Aliquid id in libero minus mollitia, nihil officia quos ratione sit soluta!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[узнать про botstrap 4 больше](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)